# How to get h264 video info?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, decoding, x264

How can I get specific h264 video information from video file? I need to know profile (Baseline/Main/High) and is there B-Frames in movie?

Comment: Just getting the information in general?  Sounds off-topic for this site.  If you're trying to get it in code, tell us more about the code.  Language, environment, etc.

Comment: What is video file? There are various container format, capable or not of storing H.264 video.

Comment: I'm looking for any possible way to determine this things, any library, any command-line application. In my work I use C# and ffmpeg app, but it can't give me special codec information.

Comment: @RomanR. It will be perfect, if solution works with all possible containers.

Comment: for a **specific** attributes, if you already know variable names for them, to process in a batch for example, it's better to use **show_entries** with ffprobe and not show_format or show_streams. I just answered [similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242630/ffmpeg-read-profile-level-information-from-mp4/36317694#36317694)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I've found out that the best way for this is using [FFprobe](http://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) with `-show_streams` parameter. It shows both h.264 profile and B-frames usage for video streams of the movie.

`ffprobe -show_streams -i "file.mp4"`

```
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=h264
codec_long_name=H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
profile=High
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=1001/48000
codec_tag_string=avc1
codec_tag=0x31637661
width=1920
height=1080
has_b_frames=0
sample_aspect_ratio=0:1
display_aspect_ratio=0:1
pix_fmt=yuv420p
level=40
timecode=N/A
is_avc=1
nal_length_size=4
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=24000/1001
avg_frame_rate=24000/1001
time_base=1/48000
start_time=0.000000
duration=252.168583
bit_rate=5617233
nb_frames=6046
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
TAG:creation_time=1970-01-01 00:00:00
TAG:language=und
TAG:handler_name=VideoHandler
[/STREAM]
```

Comment: With which tool I can get some information like GOP size?! Value for CRF and etc?!

Comment: how do u select specific streams only?

Answer (score 15):

Does mediainfo provide the output you need?
http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en

(if you're on a Mac, you can install easily with brew. > brew install media-info)

```
$ mediainfo Dream.House.sample.mkv 
General
Unique ID                        : 247222296143464620093895254679791638636 (0xB9FD4845398D136BB4A1628DB750986C)
Complete name                    : Dream.House.sample.mkv
Format                           : Matroska
Format version                   : Version 2
File size                        : 126 MiB
Duration                         : 1mn 56s
Overall bit rate                 : 9 042 Kbps
Encoded date                     : UTC 2011-12-15 03:44:07
Writing application              : mkvmerge v3.0.0 ('Hang up your Hang-Ups') built on Dec 12 2009 15:20:35
Writing library                  : libebml v0.7.9 + libmatroska v0.8.1

Video
ID                               : 1
Format                           : AVC
Format/Info                      : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                   : High@L4.1
Format settings, CABAC           : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames        : 4 frames
Codec ID                         : V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
Duration                         : 1mn 56s
Bit rate                         : 5 843 Kbps
Width                            : 1 280 pixels
Height                           : 544 pixels
Display aspect ratio             : 2.40:1
Frame rate                       : 23.976 fps
Color space                      : YUV
Chroma subsampling               : 4:2:0
Bit depth                        : 8 bits
Scan type                        : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)               : 0.350
Stream size                      : 81.5 MiB (65%)
Language                         : English

Audio #1
ID                               : 2
Format                           : DTS
Format/Info                      : Digital Theater Systems
Codec ID                         : A_DTS
Duration                         : 1mn 56s
Bit rate mode                    : Constant
Bit rate                         : 1 510 Kbps
Channel(s)                       : 6 channels
Channel positions                : Front: L C R, Side: L R, LFE
Sampling rate                    : 48.0 KHz
Bit depth                        : 24 bits
Compression mode                 : Lossy
Delay relative to video          : 67ms
Stream size                      : 21.1 MiB (17%)
Language                         : Russian

Audio #2
ID                               : 3
Format                           : DTS
Format/Info                      : Digital Theater Systems
Codec ID                         : A_DTS
Duration                         : 1mn 56s
Bit rate mode                    : Constant
Bit rate                         : 1 510 Kbps
Channel(s)                       : 6 channels
Channel positions                : Front: L C R, Side: L R, LFE
Sampling rate                    : 48.0 KHz
Bit depth                        : 24 bits
Compression mode                 : Lossy
Delay relative to video          : 67ms
Stream size                      : 21.1 MiB (17%)
Language                         : English
```

Comment: +1 worked with ubuntu 12.10 `$ sudo apt-get install mediainfo; `

Comment: mediainfo inspects the 264 format settings (e.g. CABAC) while ffprobe does not

Answer (score 9):

ffprobe, as of version 1.0.7 provides a nicely formated JSON output with the -print_format json  command switch.

You can use it like this:

> ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format Ramp\ -\ Apathy.mp3

Which produces the follwing output:

```
{
    "format": {
        "filename": "Ramp - Apathy.mp3",
        "nb_streams": 2,
        "format_name": "mp3",
        "format_long_name": "MP2/3 (MPEG audio layer 2/3)",
        "start_time": "0.000000",
        "duration": "203.638856",
        "size": "4072777",
        "bit_rate": "159999",
        "tags": {
            "title": "Apathy",
            "artist": "Ramp",
            "album": "Evolution Devolution Revolution",
            "date": "1999",
            "genre": "Metal"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ρss I have updated the answer with the proper content.

Answer (score 3):

Use [G-Spot](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=gspot%20codec&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CC8QFjAB&url=http://www.headbands.com/gspot/v26x/index.htm&ei=fOkaT_CuFoyzrAfesMGTDQ&usg=AFQjCNGTz3maUXtJol0lVlMcI37Uq90fPw&sig2=6r6olLV4mcLNbFjTmsHRmA&cad=rja) to detect the information.

Get it [here](http://www.headbands.com/gspot/v26x/GSpot270a.zip)

Comment: But it doesn't show any number for GOP size or B Frame!?