# Get MPEG-4 video stream's profile programmatically on Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, mpeg-4, mediaextractor, android-mediacodec

Is there any way to get MPEG-4 video fils's [profile-code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC#Profiles) using standard Android API?

Sample profile-codes are: `baseline`, `main`, `high` and so on.

I don't want to include `ffmpeg` binary in the android app just to get this information.

I found reference of list of profiles in [MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.html) class. Can any body confirm if this is the one I should be using?

Here is an example screenshot of video info taken from **MX Player** app
[image: Sample data with video profile]

---

- UPDATE #1: I looked into MX Player app, looks like they use `ffmpeg` binary, so I can safely say they use that to extract `profile-code`.
- UPDATE #2: I also looked into [ExoPlayer v1](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v1) APIs, they also don't seems to have specific API to get this info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Profile code can be found using `MediaExtractor`

Based on [API documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor.html#getTrackFormat(int)) it seems that the encoding **profile-code** is only available from API level 24 (Nougat) and up.

Here is method I wrote to extract the profile code, feel free to modify to meet your need.

```
/**
 * Get video profile-code from video file.
 *
 * @param videoFilePath Path of the video file.
 * @return One of predefined AVC profiles from {@link MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel} when found, or {@code -1} if
 * Android API level does not support extracting profile data.
 */
@TargetApi(21)
public int getVideoEncodingProfile(final String videoFilePath) {
    int videoProfileCode = -1;

    File inputFile = new File(videoFilePath);
    if (!inputFile.canRead()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to read " + inputFile);
    }

    MediaExtractor mediaExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
    // Initialize MediaExtractor and configure/extract video information
    try {
        mediaExtractor.setDataSource(inputFile.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to set MediaExtractor source.", e);
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to set source.");
    }

    MediaFormat videoMediaFormat = findVideoMediaFormat(mediaExtractor);
    // MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel of the video track
    if (videoMediaFormat != null && videoMediaFormat.containsKey(MediaFormat.KEY_PROFILE)) {
        videoProfileCode = videoMediaFormat.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_PROFILE);
    } else {
        // Current API level does not support encoding profile information.
        Log.w(TAG, "Video profile code is not supported by current API level.");
    }

    mediaExtractor.release();
    mediaExtractor = null;

    return videoProfileCode;
}

/**
 * Find video MediaFormat from MediaExtractor.
 *
 * @param mediaExtractor The MediaExtractor which is used to find video track.
 * @return MediaFormat for video track, or {@code null} when video track is not found.
 */
private MediaFormat findVideoMediaFormat(final MediaExtractor mediaExtractor) {
    MediaFormat videoTrackMediaFormat = null;
    int totalTracks = mediaExtractor.getTrackCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < totalTracks; i++) {
        MediaFormat trackFormat = mediaExtractor.getTrackFormat(i);
        if ((trackFormat.containsKey(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME)
                && trackFormat.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME).contains("video"))
                || (trackFormat.containsKey(MediaFormat.KEY_WIDTH) && trackFormat.containsKey(MediaFormat.KEY_HEIGHT))
                ) {
            videoTrackMediaFormat = trackFormat;
            break;
        }
    }
    return videoTrackMediaFormat;
}
```

And here is sample code on how to use it.

```
String TAG = "DEBUG"; // Define your tag
int profileCode = getVideoEncodingProfile(videoInfo.getLocalVideoPath());

switch (profileCode) {
    case MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AVCProfileBaseline:
        Log.d(TAG, "getVideoEncodingProfile() returned AVCProfileBaseline");
        break;
    case MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AVCProfileMain:
        Log.d(TAG, "getVideoEncodingProfile() returned AVCProfileMain");
        break;
    case MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AVCProfileExtended:
        Log.d(TAG, "getVideoEncodingProfile() returned AVCProfileExtended");
        break;
    case MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AVCProfileHigh:
        Log.d(TAG, "getVideoEncodingProfile() returned AVCProfileHigh");
        break;
    case MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AVCProfileHigh10:
        Log.d(TAG, "getVideoEncodingProfile() returned AVCProfileHigh10");
        break;
    case MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AVCProfileHigh422:
        Log.d(TAG, "getVideoEncodingProfile() returned AVCProfileHigh422");
        break;
    case MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AVCProfileHigh444:
        Log.d(TAG, "getVideoEncodingProfile() returned AVCProfileHigh444");
        break;
    default:
        Log.d(TAG, "getVideoEncodingProfile() returned unsupported profile code or code not found.");

}
```

Hope it helps. If you have other way which supports at least **Jelly Bean** API level `16` let me know.

---

For reference, here is a snapshot of `MediaFormat` of a video track taken from **Nougat** `7.1.1` device. *(NOTE: Lower level API will return less attributes)*

[image: MediaFormat Hash Map - Snapshot]

Other references:

- Get video file info from desktop app - [How to get h264 video info?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954609/how-to-get-h264-video-info)